# IBM Cloudant api, some issues about /_api/v2/

Tags: api, cors, cloudant

After I enabled CORS button

I can easily get resources like `cloudant.com/$dabase_name` or `cloudant.com/$dabase_name/_all_docs`

But it's not work on kinds of api like `/_api/v2`

I need to setup CORS chrome plugin to change my `Origin`

Are there any way can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `/api/v2/...` URLs are handled differently, and to my knowledge they do not follow your CORS settings.

Or, in other words, CORS is your settings for your data, but not for your *metadata* about your account.

Which API call are you trying to set? Authorization keys?

Comment: thank you!!, it''s  /api/v2/_security
.
I want generate an API key and put into `/api/v2/_security`